# Error 502 Nginx using PHP FPM (*1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php8.2-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied))

Tags: php, nginx, connection, listener, fpm

I have some problems with my nginx-configuration using php fpm. I have this error in the logs:
`*1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php8.2-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 93.31.82.197, server: www.le-max-de-culture.fr, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php8.2-fpm.sock:", host: "le-max-de-culture.fr", referrer: "https://le-max-de-culture.fr/"`

Without php (by removing index.php and the use of fpm), the configuration works well.

Here's my nginx configuration for this website:

```
server {
       root           /var/www/dev_site/prod/;

        index index.php index.html;
        server_name www.le-max-de-culture.fr le-max-de-culture.fr;

        rewrite  ^/link$  /liens.php permanent;
        rewrite  ^/lien$ /liens.php permanent;
        rewrite ^/liens$ /liens.php permanent;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
        
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php8.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }


    error_log /var/www/dev_site/prod/error_le-max-de-culture.fr.log error;
    access_log /var/www/dev_site/prod/acces_le-max-de-culture.fr.log;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/le-max-de-culture.fr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/le-max-de-culture.fr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.le-max-de-culture.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = le-max-de-culture.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name www.le-max-de-culture.fr le-max-de-culture.fr;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I try to edit the www.conf file of fpm here `/etc/php/8.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`. Yet, I have this :

```
user = nginx
group = nginx
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
```

And that seems correct with this `ls -ahl /run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock srw-rw---- 1 nginx nginx 0 27 févr. 12:41 /run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock`
I also tried with www-data without result.

Many thanks in advance !